# Transpose two variables by groups

Tags: r, transform

I have a data set that looks something like:

```
ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Time Var1 Var2
1    A      A1     A1.1   1    5   7
1    A      A1     A1.1   2    5   7
1    A      A1     A1.1   3    5   7
1    A      A1     A1.1   4    5   7
1    A      A1     A1.1   5    5   7
2    B      B1     B1.1   1    5   7
2    B      B1     B1.1   2    5   7
2    B      B1     B1.1   3    5   7
2    B      B1     B1.1   4    5   7
2    B      B1     B1.1   5    5   7
3    C      C1     C1.1   1    5   7
3    C      C1     C1.1   3    5   7
3    C      C1     C1.1   4    5   7
.
.
.
```

I'd like it to look like:

```
ID Group1 Group2 Group3 Time1 Time2 Time3...TimeN Time1 Time2 Time3...TimeN
1    A      A1     A1.1   5     5      5      5      7     7     7      7
2    B      A1     A1.1   5     5      5      5      7     7     7      7
3    C      A1     A1.1   5     5      5      5      7     7     7      7
```

Of course, not all values of Var1 are 5 and not all values of Var2 are 7 - just shown for example.

I'd like to transform the data such that each row is unique to an ID and Var1 and Var2 become columns with rows filled according to ID

I've tried

```
rave_subset <- reshape2::dcast(rave_subset, Group1 +
                          Group2 +
                          Group3 ~ Var1 + Var2, value.var = c("Var1", "Var2"))
```

But this strings together the values in Var1 and Var2 such that they print as "Var1_Var2"

If I do:

```
rave_subset <- reshape2::dcast(rave_subset, Group1 +
                          Group2 +
                          Group3 ~ Var1, value.var = "Var1")
```

Then I get nearly what I desire except that I lose Var2

Comment: Can you use `dput(my_dataframe)` so I can copy it in my Rstudio to try?

Comment: First question: is there a good reason to transform the data, such as downstream code that requires the format? I ask because it looks more useful and usable as it is (many R analyses work better with "long" format).

Comment: I tried `dcast(df, Group1 + Group2 + Group3 ~ Time, value.var = c("Var1", "Var2"))` - this does not work, I get the error `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

2) Yes, I am doing this transformation because I would like to predict Var1 at a specific timepoint using prior Var1 but in its current form I believe a regression on Var1 with lagged variables and time would violate glm assumptions 3)New to R, will look at dput

Comment: For @IcecreamToucan's suggestion to work, I believe you need to use the `data.table` version of `dcast`: `library(data.table); setDT(df1); data.table::dcast(df1, ... ~ Time, value.var = c("Var1", "Var2"), fun.aggregate = sum)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with running multiple iterations of `dcast` and `merge` - works but not the most elegant.

Code was as follows:

```
rave_subset <- subset(RAVE, !is.na(RAVE$Days) & RAVE$Days <= 180, select = c("Participant ID",
                                                          "Days",
                                                          "Randomized Treatment Group",
                                                          "AAV Type",
                                                          "ANCA Status - PR3 or MPO",
                                                          "BVAS",
                                                          "Glucocorticoid Dose (mg)",
                                                          "Cum. Pred Dose Since Last Visit (mg)",
                                                          "baseline_BVAS"))

rave_subset1 <- reshape2::dcast(rave_subset, `Participant ID` +
                                  `Randomized Treatment Group` +
                                  `AAV Type` +
                                  `ANCA Status - PR3 or MPO` +
                                  baseline_BVAS ~ Days, value.var = "BVAS")

rave_subset2 <- reshape2::dcast(rave_subset, `Participant ID` ~ Days , value.var = "Glucocorticoid Dose (mg)")

rave_subset3 <- reshape2::dcast(rave_subset, `Participant ID` ~ Days , value.var = "Cum. Pred Dose Since Last Visit (mg)")

rave_subset <- merge(x=rave_subset1,
                     y=rave_subset2,
                     by="Participant ID")

drops <- c("Randomized Treatment Group.y", "AAV Type.y", "ANCA Status - PR3 or MPO.y", "baseline_BVAS.y")
rave_subset <- rave_subset[,!(names(rave_subset) %in% drops)]

rave_subset <- merge(x=rave_subset,
                    y=rave_subset3,
                    by="Participant ID")
```